# Sticky footer in IE 8 overlaps content only after directly accessing the page

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, sticky-footer

I got a rather weird problem:

On one of the sites I'm currently creating I use a sticky footer which works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE 9.

It actually also works in IE 8, but only when accessing the site via a link from another page of the same site. When directly accessing the site (or reloading it), the footer isn't displayed at the end of the page, but a little bit above it, overlapping the content there.

If I click on an image on that page that opens in a lightbox, the footer somehow moves back to its desired place though.

The footer also works perfectly when I view the site in my local environment, the problem occurs only on the production webserver (or any other online space I uploaded it to).

Here's the relevant footer code, if you need more, please tell me (unfortunately I can't give you access to the site):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <link href="css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="content">
             <!-- Content etc goes here -->
         </div>
         <div class="push"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="footer">
         <!-- Footer goes here -->
     </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -154px;
}

div.push {
    height: 154px;
}

div.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 154px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I apprecciate any help,
tell me if you need more information or if I missed something.

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Might be a has-layout issue. Try

```
.footer {zoom: 1;}
```

Comment: I kind of solved it - I noticed that this only happens when the content area ends with a picture instead of text, so I assigned a "min-height" to the picture, which did the trick.

The value for min-height (or height) has to match the desired height of the picture though, and since the content's going to be dynamic, I can't really use that "solution".

Adding .footer { zoom: 1; } unfortunately doesn't change the behaviour.